# blinker circuit theory

Tags: oscillator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSrUbg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A simple light bulb blinker circuit.......R4 is the bulb..I'm pretty sure I understand the functionality here. C1 initially starts to charge allowing Q1 to turn on. Once Q1 turns on the collector current of Q1 turns Q2 on hard and the base of R4 goes to approx 0v. This causes the right side of C1 to start to discharge through R2 and Q2.

My question is why does the voltage on the left side of C1 increase enough during the time the right side is discharging to turn off Q1. I see from simulations that this is what happens but I'm not sure why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 100 ohm resistor driving the base of Q2 is not really low enough to drive it deep into saturation with a 3 ohm load, nor is the 120K resistor low enough to drive Q1 deep into saturation with a 100 ohm load, so there is positive feedback from the collector of Q2 to the base of Q1.

As the voltage rises on Q2's collector (because the base current is dropping as the capacitor discharges through R2) it causes the base current of Q1 to drop and thus the base current of Q2, and at some point Q2 snaps off driving Q1 off and allowing the capacitor to charge through R4.

If the load resistance is increased to (say) 300 ohms you'll probably see the circuit fail to operate.

Comment: "it causes the base current of Q1 to drop and thus the base current of Q1". Was one of these supposed to be Q2 or was this an unfinished thought?

Comment: thanks...I understand now. BTW only needed to change the load to 6 ohms and the circuit didn't oscillate..

Comment: @HaNguyen Yes, this circuit could be considered a bit dubious since it depends a lot on the transistor beta. Maybe it will stop working with some transistors of a given type at temperature extremes, for example.